# Modelagem Bancos Instituição Financeira

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, postgresql, modelagem, tabela-banco-de-dados

Estou iniciando um projeto pessoal para meu aprendizado, um aplicativo simulando um sistema de instituição financeira, primeiramente utilizaria os seguintes produtos: conta-corrente, contrato de crédito (empréstimos). Me deparei com a seguinte dificuldade, qual seria a melhor forma de modelar os saldos de conta corrente diariamente e o mesmo vale para o produto de crédito?

Atualmente essa seria a tabela de conta corrente:

```
id_cliente - inteiro, fk
num_conta - inteiro
tipo_conta - inteiro, fk
situacao_conta - inteiro, fk
data_abertura - data
data_encerramento - data
```

Pensei em criar uma tabela saldo_cc e armazenar o número da conta saldo e data, seria essa uma boa ideia?

Comment: Pense que para o saldo mudar deve haver um evento, uma "movimentação". Poderia criar uma tabela "Movimentacao" com a FK para "conta corrente", que tiversse a data, descrição e valor do movimento (saque, transferência, etc) além do saldo. Apenas sugestão pessoal

Comment: faz a tabela de movimentacao e grava `saldo_anterior`, `valor` e `saldo_atual` da conta... a cada insert o valor é atualizado. Lembrando que nessa tabela, não pode haver update, apenas insert. Dessa forma você tem saldo anterior e saldo atual de qualquer período. Se puder ter movimentos retroativos, aí não tem jeito, o saldo tem que ser calculado em cima do período informado.